# Grouping low frequency levels of categorical variables to improve machine learning performance

Tags: python, machine-learning

I'm trying to find ways to improve performance of machine learning models either binary classification, regression or multinomial classification.

I'm now looking at the topic categorical variables and trying to combine low occuring levels together. Let's say a categorical variable has 10 levels where 5 levels account for 85% of the total frequency count and the 5 levels remaining account for the 15% remaining.

I'm currently trying different thresholds (30%, 20%, 10%) to combine levels together. This means I combine together the levels which represent either 30%, 20% or 10% of the remaining counts.

I was wondering if grouping these "low frequency groups" into a new level called "others" would have any benefit in improving the performance.

I further use a random forest for feature selection and I know that having fewer levels than orignally may create a loss of information and therefore not improve my performance.

Also, I tried discretizing numeric variables but noticed that my performance was weaker because random forests benefit from having the hability to split on their preferred split point rather than being forced to split on an engineered split point that I would have created by discretizing.

In your experience, would grouping low occuring levels together have a positive impact on performance ? If yes, would you recommend any techniques ?

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Not a *programming* question, hence arguably off-topic here; perhaps suited for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Question is about categorical variables, not classes.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a programming question... By having fewer classes, you inherently increase the chance of randomly predicting the correct class.

Consider a stacked model (two models) where you have a primary model to classify between the overrepresented classes and the 'other' class, and then have a secondary model to classify between the classes within the 'other' class if the primary model predicts the 'other' class.

Comment: Question is about categorical variables, not classes.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered similar question and this what I managed to find to this point:

1. Try numerical feature encoding on high cardinality categorical features.
   There is very good library for that: [category_encoders](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/category_encoders). And also [medium article](https://towardsdatascience.com/smarter-ways-to-encode-categorical-data-for-machine-learning-part-1-of-3-6dca2f71b159) describing some of the methods.

Sources

- https://www.kaggle.com/general/16927
- https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/411767/encoding-of-categorical-variables-with-high-cardinality
- https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/37819/ml-models-how-to-handle-categorical-feature-with-over-1000-unique-values?newreg=f16addec41734d30bb12a845a32fe132

2. Cut features with low frequencies as you proposed initially. Threshold is arbitrary and usually is 1-10% of train samples. scikit-learn [has option for this](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#infrequent-categories) in it's OneHotEncoder transformer.

Sources

- https://towardsdatascience.com/dealing-with-features-that-have-high-cardinality-1c9212d7ff1b
- https://www.kaggle.com/general/16927